# Why @Autowired annotation associate every bean of the same class into context.xml?

Tags: java, xml, spring, annotations, autowired

**Context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />

<bean id="foo" class="annotation.Foo">
    <property name="name" value="firstFoo"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="secondaryFoo" class="annotation.Foo">
    <property name="name" value="secondaryFoo"></property>
    <qualifier value="secondaryFoo"></qualifier>
</bean>
<bean id="bar" class="annotation.Bar" />
```

**Bar:**

```
public class Bar {

@Autowired
@Qualifier(value="secondaryFoo")
private Foo foo;

public void setFoo(Foo foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
}
public void  printFooName(){
    System.out.println("\nBar class: foo.getName(): "+foo.getName()+"\n");      
}

}
```

**Foo:**

```
public class Foo {
private String name;

public Foo(){
    System.out.println("\nFoo class: Constructor invoked, name: "+ name + "\n");
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    System.out.println("\nFoo class: @PostConstruct Bean Foo successfully initialized, name: " + name +"\n");
}
@PreDestroy
public void cleanUp() {
    System.out.println("*\nFoo class: @PreDestroy clean up called\n");
}
}
```

**Main:**

```
public class TestFooBar {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    System.out.println("\nMain invoked\n");

    AbstractApplicationContext applicationContext = 
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("annotation/annotation.xml");

    Bar bar = applicationContext.getBean("bar", Bar.class);

    bar.printFooName();

}

}
```

When I run the application the System out are printed in this order:

```
- Main invoked 
- Foo class: Constructor invoked, name: null 
- Foo class: @PostConstruct Bean Foo successfully initialized, name: firstFoo 
- Foo class: Constructor invoked, name: null 
- Foo class: @PostConstruct Bean Foo successfully initialized, name: secondaryFoo 
- Bar class: foo.getName(): secondaryFoo
```

If I specified in the Bar class (@Autowired @Qualifier(value="secondary Foo")) the bean with secondary Foo id, why the beans, in te context, are instantiated both?

If I remove this two annotations, the result of the System out is the same! How it is possible?

Answer (score 2):

You specify both `Foo` beans in your `annotation.xml` context, so Spring instantiates both of them (as well as your `bar` bean).

Then, in addition, it injects `secondaryFoo` as a dependency into your `bar` bean.

If you don't want the beans automatically created you could declare them as `lazy-init="true"` in `annotation.xml`

Comment: Like this? `<bean id="secondaryFoo" class="annotation.Foo" lazy-init="true">` ... With *lazy="true"* Spring gives me this error: **org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException**

Comment: But I saw that with lazy property the beans are instantiated both the same. The difference is only the order of instancing. Right? I need that only *firstFoo* was instantiated. It's possibile do that?

Comment: If you only want firstFoo instantiating what would you expect to be injected into bar?  Lazy-init would defer the initialisation until it is needed, I.e injected into another bean or looked up from the context. If you declare both first and second foo as lazy, the as you don't use firstFoo anywhere it should be instantiated. Hope that helps.